# How to retrieve data from database using jOOQ based on jsontype properties

Tags: java, sql, jooq

we have a Employee table with json type address column like mentioned below

**Employee Table:**

[image]

How to retrieve the Employee details based on city name which is in address column using jOOQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`JSON_VALUE()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-value-function/) support of jOOQ:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(EMPLOYEE)
   .where(cast(jsonValue(EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS, "$.city"), VARCHAR).eq("\"Mumbai\""))
   .fetch();
```

This is assuming you use code generation and have the usual static imports:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.*;
```

If you need support for any other vendor-specific JSON function that jOOQ doesn't support (yet), use plain SQL templating instead.

However, that approach is unlikely to take advantage of indexes, so if you can, I suggest normalising this data.

Comment: Doesn't work, It always returns 0 rows. I have used getSQL() function to see the output

with cast() in place:
select `employee `.`name` from `employee`
where cast(json_extract(`employee`.`address`, ?) as char) = ?

select `employee `.`name` from `employee`
where cast(json_extract(`employee`.`address`, "$.city") as char) = "Delhi"; which always returns 0 rows

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The extracted content is a JSON string, not a SQL string. Try again the updated answer, see also this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c9fe7638cb01c0bc93ef6c750aa84f3)

Comment: Worked!! I have an alternative way of doing this which also works without the escape characters

ctx.selectFrom(EMPLOYEE)
   .where(DSL.field("json_extract(`employee`.`address`, "$.car")", VARCHAR).eq("Mumbai"))
   .fetch();

Comment: Yes, sure, you can always resort to using plain SQL templates